# How to extract MSSQLServer database as .dacpac without VerifyExtraction?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms, data-tier-applications

I want to extract a database schema of a MSSQLServer database with Server Management Studio. I use the Extract command "Extract Data-tier Application.."

In the database are several references to another database. Because of this I get the following error.

**Error extracting database: Validation of the schema model for data package failed.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[x] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[y]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.**

The problem is, that SSMS uses the SQLPackage.exe with parameter ***/p:VerifyExtraction=True***. When I use the console and call SQLPackage.exe without this Parameter, it uses ***/p:VerifyExtraction=False*** by default and I can create the .dacpac file.

Is there a way to configure SSMS to disable verification?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a method that works in SSMS (2008 R2 or 2012), either, but Visual Studio (2013) with SSDT seems to work:  Within VS, go to SQL Server Object Explorer, connect to the server in question, right click the database in question, Extract Data-tier Application, and then adjust the Extract Settings, one of which is "Verify extraction".  I don't know why MS doesn't just build that into SSMS.

One somewhat-odd thing I noticed from doing, this, though, is that VS will only extract a .DacPac via this method.  Even when you choose to add data to the extract, the extension is still .DacPac.  I was under the impression that .DacPacs were solely for Schema Only, while .BacPacs were for Schema + Data.  Regardless, after VS created the .DacPac (Schema + Data) file, SSMS was able to import it fine using "Deploy Data-tier Application..." wizard.

Answer (score 35):

If you cannot use Visual Studio you can use the command line `SqlPackage` application to extract the schema from the database. By default, this **does not** verify the schema (no, I don't know why SSMS and the command line offering have different defaults!). `SqlPackage.exe` can be found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\<SQL_VERSION>\DAC\bin`.

For example, the following extracts the schema for `MyDatabase` from the local SQL Server instance and outputs it to a `.dacpac` file on the local filesystem:

```
sqlpackage /Action:Extract /SourceDatabaseName:"MyDatabase" /SourceServerName:localhost /TargetFile:"C:\SomeDirectory\MyDatabase.dacpac"
```

If you want to include schema verification at a later stage, you can set the flag explicitly by adding `/p:VerifyExtraction=True` to the command line.

Full information on `SqlPackage.exe` can be found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh550080.aspx

Comment: After chasing my tail for hours with non functioning powershell scripts, inconsistent assemblies and versions (and I admit lack of experience with Powershell), this worked immediately.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks for the comment, I'm really glad to hear it helped.

Comment: Appears location for SSMS 17.5 is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe`

Comment: @yvesva Thanks! Yes, different versions of SQL Server and its tools are stored under separate numbered directories, with `140` corresponding to SQL Server 2017. Instead of hard-coding one of these in my answer, I've now just put `<SQL_VERSION>` instead.

Comment: @DaveR. suppose I am trying to extract from Azure SQL Managed Instance. Can I do that with PowerShell also?

Comment: @CB_Ron According to the sqlpackage release notes, support for MI was added last year: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/tools/release-notes-sqlpackage?view=sql-server-2017 Both PowerShell and the command line should behave the same.

Comment: @DaveR. Sadly, when using sqlpackage with the `/Action:Export` switch, Verify is not a valid property. So I still cannot export both the schema **and** data.

Comment: Hi @CB_Ron. Are you sure you're using `VerifyExtraction` and not just `Verify` as the property value?Also, the original question was for schema-only dacpac extraction, I'm afraid. It may be better to author a new question for your particular requirements if you're still having no luck. Sorry my answer didn't help.

Comment: @DaveR. Yes I did use that parameter. It is not valid for `/Action:Export`, verified by the links in your post. I have asked a new question over on dba StackExchange. I'm in the process of testing one of those answers right now.

Comment: @CB_Ron Use the `Extract` action, not `Export`. You're correct that export doesn't support verification; sorry I didn't spot that when answering you previously.